# How to read a file from parent folder using firebase functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

```
app.get('/sign-in', (req, res) =>{
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(fs.readFileSync('../html/Login.html'));
})

app.get('/sign-up', (req, res) =>{
    console.log('connecting sign-up BABY');
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(fs.readFileSync('../html/Register.html'));
})
```

As you can see I'm using fs.readFilesync to call html file. It's weird because it works on the localhost by using `firebase serve` but it doesn't work on the firebase server after deploy. Error message is more confusing. It only says `Error: could not handle the request` and the console shows

```
Function execution started
Function execution took 1559 ms, finished with status: 'connection error'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy your Cloud Functions, Firebase deploys the files that are in the `functions` folder. It seems like your code is trying to read a file from a different folder. And since that folder hasn't been deployed to Cloud Functions, it fails.

Any content that you read from your Cloud Functions code, should be in/under the `functions` folder. You might want to move/copy the `html` folder into the `files` folder just before deploying.